# Iterating over a VBA.Collections in C#

Tags: c#, vba, collections

I'm working on some code in my COOP and I have a parameter for a method which is of type `VBA.Collection`. I'm trying to see what's inside of it but I can't find a way to iterate over it. The only methods that it has are

- Add
- Count
- Equals
- GetEnumerator
- GetHashCode
- GetType
- Item
- Remove
- ToString

I tried using the Item method but it has `ref Object index` as a parameter, and it also can't be used as a an array.

Any help on this would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire purpose of `GetEnumerator` is to allow iteration of the type.  If you want to iterate it, use that.

You could, for example, do:

```
foreach(object item in collection)
{
    //use item here
}
```

Comment: The foreach was causing an exception for me, let me try it with object.

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon Then you should mention that in your question, along with the exact error message and code you were using.

Comment: I know I'm sorry, I've been so frustrated with this I seem to have forgotten that part. I'm just starting to code in C#, coming from Java and even though they're similar, some of the terminology changes and I get a bit lost.